# Dillinger stuck at "prepping all the things" when running locally

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, browserify

**Update**: I have checked the console for error, it catches

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

According to some online posts, it is probably due to the use of `require` on the browser side. `require` is meant to be a syntax for Node, which is used on the server side. But the use of [Browserify][browserify.org/] made this possible.

Im not sure how this works but hope someone may give me some advice.

---

I was trying to run [Dillinger](https://github.com/joemccann/dillinger) on my own Macbook Pro (13-inch)

I followed the instructions on the README.md but when running locally it shows this.

PS. As suggested by [post](https://github.com/joemccann/dillinger/issues/296) here, I modified the package.json that the dependency installation can proceed.

> Dropbox config not found at /Users/[name]/dev/dillinger/plugins/dropbox/dropbox-config.json. Plugin disabled.
>
> Github config not found at /Users/[name]/dev/dillinger/plugins/github/github-config.json. Plugin disabled.
>
> Google Drive config not found at /Users/[name]/dev/dillinger/plugins/googledrive/googledrive-config.json. Plugin disabled.
>
> OneDrive config not found at /Users/[name]/dev/dillinger/plugins/onedrive/onedrive-config.json. Plugin disabled.
>
> express deprecated app.configure: Check app.get('env') in an if
>   statement app.js:19:5
>
> connect deprecated multipart: use parser (multiparty, busboy,
>   formidable) npm module instead
>   node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js:56:20
>
> connect deprecated limit: Restrict request size at location of read
>   node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/multipart.js:86:15
>
> connect deprecated methodOverride: use method-override npm module
>   instead app.js:27:19
>
> express deprecated app.configure: Check app.get('env') in an if
>   statement app.js:56:5
>
> Express server listening on port 8080
>
> http://localhost:8080

When I send a request, it shows this :

> Evernote not implemented yet.
>
> GET / 200 34.139 ms - -
>
> GET /css/app.css 304 4.351 ms - -

Then when I tried to open Dillinger at localhost, it is stuck at **"Prepping all the things..."**

Anyone has any idea why this is so? I am new to Javascript and Node.JS so forgive me if the question looks dumb.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Which steps have you done?

Comment: @zaynetro I have done all the steps from the README. so it's after the last step that I got these notification